# Как загрузить фикстуры перед каждым rspec тестом rails

Tags: rspec-rails

Проблема в том что после каждого теста database_cleaner чистит тестовую базу, но не загружает фикстуры заново. **Как сделать чтобы он подгружал фикстуры в базу сразу после очистки?**

Пробовал:

- перед каждым тестом ставить `fixtures :all`
- в `database_cleaner.rb` ставить

`config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. В rails_helper.rb нужно поставить `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`, тогда фикстурами будет управлять database_cleaner